# Simplifing and Index + match function use

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I am using the INDEX + MATCH excel function to look for an specific data on that named range. As my "MATCH" column is the second column (column "B"), I need to use the OFFSET function on that.

An excel example formula is this :

```
=INDEX(Macro;MATCH($F$29;OFFSET(Macro;0;1;;1);0);MATCH(J$2;Macro!$2:$2;0)))
```

So, to avoid having that function on all over my spreadsheet, I want to create a function to return such data.

I am trying to create the INDEX + MATCH on VBA and it works, by as soon as a try to use the named range (plus the OFFSET), I get some errors.

This gives me error :

```
DADOSMACRO = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("DataIWant"), Range("Macro").Offset(, 1), 0)"
```

This works :

```
"DADOSMACRO = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("DataIWant"), Range("Macro!A8:A37").Offset(, 1), 0)"
```

Full function:

```vb
Public Function DADOSMACRO() As String 
    DADOSMACRO = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("$F$29"), _
                                      Range("Macro").Offset(, 1), 0) 
End Function
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code you have so far

Comment: As I sad I am trying to convert an existing excel formula into a VBA code. The code so far is "Public Function DADOSMACRO() As String


DADOSMACRO = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("$F$29"), Range("Macro").Offset(, 1), 0)



End Function
"

Comment: "I get some errors" is not a very useful description of what you're seeing.

Comment: `Range("$F$29")` without a specific worksheet will always default to the ActiveSheet, so you may get errors or the wrong result if a different sheet is active.

Comment: But named ranges are usable across all workbook. If I run this VBA code, it works perfectly an set my range as Italic (Range("Macro").Font.Italic = TRUE)

Comment: I realized that the error is regard that the range is "Macro!8:37", not "Macro!A8:Z37" for example. Is that the range does not have and column on its definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everybody who tried to help. I finally could solve it with some help from Microsoft support.

The problem is not regarding using named ranges. The problem is that the named range is a range of whole rows, so the offset VBA function does not work.

I finally made it work replacing the offset by `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("CELL_I_WANT_FIND"), Range("NAMEDRANGE").Columns(2), 0)`

So the match vba code could find the data on column "B"